# list of pointers initialize and release memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, linked-list

When using list what are the good habits to manage memory,

dynamic allocation and release (free) wheneve we dont need it anymore. To keep program light and avoid memory leaks ensure a good memory managment (i now it's a wide question)

1. how to initialize a list of pointers to objects initially with N items ? should i use the operator new to allocate memory?
2. if i want to delete completely (free) an item from a list and program memory space, should i use pop or remove or erase ? differences?
3. should i use operator delete while iterating a list or .erase .remove is enough to free space ?

.

```
   class myclass { /* whatever attributes, methodes */  };

    list<myclass *> lst (5); //5 pointers will be NULL this way

for (list<myclass *>::iterator it=lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); it++)  {
   myclass *obj= *it;
   delete obj;              //error
   it = lst.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and avoid raw owning pointers.

Comment: i dont even know what a smart pointer is i am not familiar with c++

Comment: BTW, `std::list<myclass> lst` seems enough in your case.

Comment: The list, and related containers in C++, are designed to hold the objects and handle all of the memory management for you. Unless you have a really good reason to, don't use pointers at all.

Comment: If you want to learn about pointers you should play with pointers. Don't involve a container like `std::list` until you understand pointers.

Comment: @Beta: That is possibly a fair point for list, which is a specialized container. It certainly does not apply to `std::vector` which should be your default container.

Comment: @MSalters: Why doesn't it apply to `std::vector`? How does putting pointers in a vector make them easier to understand?

Comment: @Beta: That's still a bad idea, but the point was that you should learn to use `vector` before you learn pointers. Pointers suffer from a major case of poorly defined semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I think you should listen to what everyone else said, I figured I would still answer your questions so you know the answer should you need to know them. Smart pointers are definitely best to use nowadays, but when I learned pointers in C++, I initially used new/delete and I feel it helps you understand better than just going straight to smart pointers (I know you said you don't know what they are, so they just manage the memory for you).

> how to initialize a list of pointers to objects initially with N items ? should i use the operator new to allocate memory?

As you did, `list<myclass *> lst (5)` would be just fine to make your list of pointers, and yes, you should use new for each of the elements in the list in order to allocate memory there. For example,

```
list<myclass*>::iterator it = lst.begin();
*it = new myclass();
```

> if i want to delete completely (free) an item from a list and program memory space, should i use pop or remove or erase ? differences?

To get rid of an element from the list, you can use the list's erase function found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/
That will remove the element from the list, however be careful here if using pointers, because you'll need to make sure that you free the pointer that the list node was holding before you erase this node (see below)

> should i use operator delete while iterating a list or .erase .remove is enough to free space ?

.erase will delete the element from the list, but it will not free the pointer for you, you will would explicitly need to do something like this.

```
list<myclass*> lst(5);
list<myclass*>::iterator it = lst.begin();
*it = new myclass();
// and when you're ready to delete a node
if(*it != NULL)
     delete *it;
     lst.erase(it);
```

Also, in your for loop, be sure to check, as I do, if the pointer is NULL before deleting it. This is likely why you got an error on the delete call. Since it is not allowed to store memory at NULL, it is clearly not allowed to delete the memory there. That will give you a segmentation fault. It's always good to check for NULL before deleting just in case unless you are positive it will be holding data.

Hope this helps. It's not the best way to do it with newer versions of C++ available, but it should answer your question as asked.

Comment: thanks it does answer my question i will look to smart pointers later, i forget should i set ptr to NULL after delete or it is useless   delete ptr;  ptr = 0;

Comment: If you intend on deleting that list element right away, there is no need since that variable will be deleted along with the list element, but if you are just removing what the pointer points to and not the list element, definitely DO set it to NULL. It might just be best practice to for now always set it to NULL until you understand C++ a little better. It's better to be safer than sorry. Also, please upvote if it helped! I'm try to get my reputation up! Just started using this site. ;D

Answer (score 1):

C++ has value semantics. A list owns the objects on it. This is true whether it's a list of `int` (built-in type), `std::string` (library type) or `myclass` (yours). Make sure that your class can be copied (or at least moved, but that's an advanced topic). Also make sure that your class destructor works properly, because `list::clear` will call it.

Do not try to use lists of pointers, initially. When you do, use lists of *smart* pointers, but that is already an advanced topic. Lists of "dumb" pointers should be avoided outright.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how to initialize a list of pointers to objects initially with N items ? should i use the operator new to allocate memory?

Don't. Let the list handle the allocation and deallocation.

```
lst.push_back(myclass());
```

If you have a number of items to go into the list, you can take advantage of initializers. The following uses a myclass constructor that takes a string and an int as an example.

```
list<myclass> lst {{"one", 1},{"two", 2},{"three", 3}};
```

If this is an assignment which requires pointer use, definitely use `new` rather than `malloc` and it's family to allocate storage, but consider this a last resort.

Preferred would be to use a smart pointer. The big two of these are [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

```
list<unique_ptr<myclass>> lst;

lst.push_back(unique_ptr<myclass>(new myclass()));
```

or in C++14 or newer,

```
lst.push_back(make_unique<myclass>());
```

The unique_ptr automatically destroys the myclass when removed from the list.

But I see no advantage to this over the list directly containing myclass unless myclass is the base class of a class hierarchy. If you are in the early stages of learning C++, do some reading and practice of the basics before going this route.

```
list<shared_ptr<myclass>> lst;

lst.push_back(shared_ptr<myclass>(new myclass()));
```

Makes a reference-counted my class that can be shared with others. When every user has disposed of their shared_ptr, the myclass will be destroyed. This is great for systems with callbacks. The callback object will be there when the callback fires, preventing all sorts of fun segfaults. The downside is the lifetime of the object is blurred. When it is destroyed depends on the outstanding shared_ptrs.

Do not allow circular references of shared_ptrs, as the reference count will never drop to zero. There might be some really sneaky code built in to assist here, but I wouldn't count on it. Bad program design anyway.

Raw pointer with `new`. Just don't do this. You have better, safer options.

```
lst.push_back(new myclass());
```

> 2. if i want to delete completely (free) an item from a list and program memory space, should i use pop or remove or erase ? differences?

`remove` doesn't exist for list. Pop, depending on which one you use, either removes the [first](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front) or [last](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back) element. Use pop if the list represents a queue or a stack. [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) can remove any element, so long as you know where it is. Finding it may require a search.

With a stored object, `list<myclass>` you might not get any memory back. The list may save the allocated RAM so it doesn't have to ask for it again later. Frankly I'm not sure what the standard's policy is for lists. For [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s, the object is destroyed, but the space remains allocated unless you manually force a resizing. I believe list behaves the same way because of the presence of the [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/resize) method and the wording of the documentation.

If you have a raw pointer, you must `delete` it, then remove it from the list. You can't do it in the other order because once removed from the list the pointer is inaccessible and the RAM is lost to you. Yeah, you can copy the pointer, then remove it from the list, then delete the copy, but why go to the extra effort? I believe the pointer will still be allocated in the list, but will be inaccessible and awaiting reuse.

If you use a unique_ptr, the unique_ptr handles the disposal for you. With a shared_ptr, disposal is also handled for you, but you don't necessarily know when. Another copy of the shared_ptr may exist, blocking destruction.

> 3. should i use operator delete while iterating a list or .erase .remove is enough to free space ?

Covered above in my answer to 2. With a pointer, removal from the list only removes the pointer to myclass and leaves you without a pointer to myclass and the RAM is lost. With a smart pointer, the myclass is destroyed by the smart pointer with no further effort required.

But you may not get any noticeable amount of RAM back if it is being held by the list for reuse.